# Even terms and odd terms diverge imply the the original series diverge

Tags: real-analysis

If I split an alternating series into even and odd parts and show both parts diverge, can I conclude the original series diverge?

Comment: Have you looked at an example?  Try the alternating harmonic series, $\sum\frac { (-1)^n}n$.

Comment: So, this is only true if the terms of the series all have the same sign.